# Should I use T-score or Z-score for this problem?

Tags: statistics

The farmer decides to try out a new type of pumpkin. A small sample crop with $10$ plants is grown. We first assume that the 10 weight measurements $Y_1, Y_2,. . . , Y_{10}$ are independent and normally distributed with unknown expectation $\mu_Y$ and known standard deviation $\sigma_Y = 0.8$.
The results of the measurements are given in the list below:
$$3.7 , 2.2 , 1.8 , 4.5 , 2.4 , 2.5 , 2.6 , 2.1 , 2.5 , 2.2$$

Find a $90$% confidence interval for $\mu_Y$.

So I am wondering if I should use t-score or z-score for this problem?

Comment: Read the assumptions for $t$ test and for $z$ test. They differ in one crucial point, which is explicitly stated in the problem text.

Comment: In most cases I know when to use z-score and t-score. I have been told that t-score should be used when we don't know the standard deviation. But here we know it, but the mean is unknown. I have not come across such a problem before

Comment: Use z when population $\sigma$ is known, use t when it's not. I get $\bar X = 2.85$ and 90% z CI for $\mu$ about $(2.23, 3.07).$ // If $\sigma$ not known, then you have less information and (wider) t CI about $(2.17, 3.1).$

Comment: @BruceET. So you use the z-score to calculate the confidence interval then, even when the mean is not known?

Comment: The _population_ mean $\mu$ is unknown. It's _point_ estimate is $\bar X = 2.85$ and the 90% z CI gives an idea how close to $\mu$ the estimate $2.85$ might be.  // if we know $\sigma$ and don't have to estimate it by the sample SD $S,$ then we can get a narrower CI using z.

Comment: Ok, I will use the z-score then. Thank you for your help :)